# Powershell .net Code slow since MS-Security Update April 2019

Tags: .net, powershell, windows-server-2016, windows-update

Since May 2019 Security Rollup for Windows Server 2016, access to .net object via powershell is very slow, when a powershell variable breakpoint is set in the powershell.

For example loading speed of [System.Environment] takes over ten times with breakpoint set against no breakpoint set.

Since the behavior only occurs with latest security updates installed (May 2019 (KB4494440) or June 2019 (KB4503267)) i think it is related to the update.

Did some troubleshooting with procmon until now. For me it looks like when PSBreakpoint is set, there are multiple reads from `HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment\__PSLockdownPolicy` can't repoduce this when there is no breakpoint set and can't reproduce this effect without one of the updates installed.

Following powershell code runs more than 10 times slower when i install Windows Security Rollup update Mai / June 2019 on my Windows Server 2016.

```
$measure1 = measure-command{
  foreach($i in 1..10000){
    [System.Environment]
  }
} |select -ExpandProperty TotalSeconds

Set-PSBreakpoint -Variable "test" -Action {$null}

$measure2 = measure-command{
  foreach($i in 1..10000){
    [System.Environment]
  }
} |select -ExpandProperty TotalSeconds

Write-Host "First measurement took $measure1 seconds, Second measurement took $measure2"

>>First measurement took 0.0482474 seconds, Second measurement took 0.8722697
```

Can anyone observe this behavior as well?

Do you have any suggestions to workaround this problem?

Is it related to some settings or installed software?

Comment: It sounds like you should file an issue on the MS PowerShell GitHub repo.

Comment: I don't have Server 2016, but on other machines, after a Windows update when things start to go slow, it helps running [Ngen.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/ngen-exe-native-image-generator)

Comment: Windows 10, Powershell **5.1**: `0.0109209 / 3.2646145`, Powershell **6.2**: `0.0052287 / 0.0078765`